# Traduction de « hook » dans un contexte de programmation

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

Comme semble-t-il beaucoup d'entre vous, je suis programmeur. La majeure partie du vocabulaire en programmation vient de l'anglais, et une bonne partie des mots utilisés correspondent à des mots courants anglais, souvent issus du vocabulaire de la vie de tous les jours.

J'ai pu trouver à plusieurs reprises l'utilisation du mot « hook » (usuellement utilisé pour « crochet » ou « hameçon »), mais sans jamais réussir à trouver une traduction correcte dans ce contexte-là. Par exemple, l'expression « import hook » revient souvent en Python. On parle également de « hook functions ».

Quelle serait la traduction la plus appropriée en français ?

Comment: http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=anglais&query=hook+functions ne propose pas grand chose dans ce domaine

Comment: @cl-r Oui, c'est bien le problème. J'aime bien parler de programmation en utilisant un maximum de mots français - ou du moins qui semblent avoir des racines grecques ou latines -, et celui-ci me bloque^^"

Comment: Une *fonction accrocheuse*? Une *fonction hameçonneuse*?

Comment: @AlexisPigeon Très souvent, le mot est utilisé en tant que nom et non en tant qu'adjectif (« something hook » est plus courant que « hook something »). Par conséquent, c'est cette forme qui m'intéresse le plus.

Comment: *Crochet fonctionnel*? *Code crochet*? Mais je dois dire que j'ai jamais vraiment compris le besoin de traduire les termes techniques en programmation. Ca mène souvent à des termes au mieux bancals, le plus souvent mal ou pas compris par les autres...

Comment: Et je n'ai jamais entendu parler de *hook* en tant que nom en programmation, mais toujours en tant qu'adjectif, même si la plupart du temps le nom auquel il se rattache (*function*, *script*, etc.) est implicite et donc omis. Mais je dois avouer que je ne connais pas Python...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Je rencontre souvent ce terme, en tant que programmeur.

En général (non spécifiquement à Python donc), un *hook* est une opportunité laissée au programmeur ou à l'utilisateur de modifier le fonctionnement d'un code préexistant. Cela peut se faire par l'emploi de code client spécifique ou encore de fichiers scripts, par exemple. Je n'ose développer plus, ce site n'est pas le lieu approprié pour trop parler technique, mais il est facile de trouver des exemples par quelques recherches.

Les seules fois où je l'ai vu traduit, *hook* l'était littéralement: *crochet*. Cependant, *point d'ancrage*, voire *point de branchement* me semblerait très correct. 
A la limite, si l'opportunité de modification est involontaire, on pourrait parler de *point d'injection*. Je pense entre autres choses à l'injection SQL.

Comment: Hum, c'est vrai qu'on peut prendre le terme *crochet* dans son sens *détour* ; ça lui donne alors du sens en français également.

Comment: Oui, et s'y ajoute l'idée de crocheter, d'attraper la chose et la tordre un peu :)

Answer (score 3):

Bien que je ne connaisse pas Python, peut-être faut-il se baser sur **point d'attache** ou encore *point d'ancrage* :

> - *importation des points attaches*
> - *fonction d'accrochage*
> - *les ancrages* de ces variables sont définis ...
> - ... y *[r]accrocher* la propriété pour la fiabilité du code.

Il me semble que cela dépend beaucoup du contexte et du chapitre de l'ouvrage, j'aurais tendance à :

- essayer de franciser ces notions dans les commentaires,
- donner leur traduction et mettre le mot anglais entre accolades dans les définitions,
- ...  et laisser le mot original dans les zones de pures techniques.

Autant l'enjeu de traduire le maximum de mots, d'idées ou de concepts est passionnant et laisse un espace à la créativité, autant l'absolutisme 'psychorigide' est à bannir pour rester passeur de langues bien vivantes.

Comment: Je confirme que la traduction ne sert à rien dans certains cas, mais parfois, le résultats sonne étonnamment bien, est clair et donne une idée du concept. Il est plus simple d'exprimer des idées s'il existe des mots pour.

Comment: Merci pour cette proposition intéressante, très parlante. J'aurais ajouté aussi la variante *point d'accroche*.

Answer (score 2):

Chez Apple, la possibilité d'accrocher du code à de l'existant est couverte par la notion de délégation.